# What's a cantrip?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, terminology

In discussions of Magic cards, I've heard a card called a *cantrip* on several occasions, but I haven't been able to find a definition of what that term means for MtG. Is a cantrip a particular card, a card with a particular mechanism, or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A cantrip is any spell that allows you to draw a card in addition to it's regular effect (e.g. [Peek](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=130903)).  It is typically of low casting cost, and the drawing is a secondary effect.

Comment: The original cantrips were in Ice Age, and typically read "draw a card at the beginning of next turn's upkeep".  Eventually Wizards decided that was too much faff and changed the card-draw to be an immediate effect.  Some people call the Ice Age cards "slowtrips" as a result!